# doc_count different from count, sum does not match total during elasticsearch with aggregation

Tags: svn, elasticsearch

Good day guys. I have very strange issue when trying to collect data with elastic search. I am storing data from SVN line changes by Languages, extensions and modules. For this sections I use terms for search.
Here is example:
data is stored in form:

```
_source: {
files: 3,
revision_change: {
    add: {
        detail: {
            total: 76124,
            source: [
                {
                    lines: 76124,
                    key: "human"
                }
            ],
            extension: [
                {
                    lines: 18,
                    key: "without_extension"
                },
                {
                    lines: 5,
                    key: "py"
                },
                {
                    lines: 76101,
                    key: "sql"
                }
            ],
            language: [
                {
                    lines: 5,
                    key: "Python"
                },
                {
                    lines: 18,
                    key: "Undefined"
                },
                {
                    lines: 76101,
                    key: "SQL"
                }
            ],
            module: [

            ]
        }
    },
    remove: {
        detail: {
            total: 74573,
            source: [
                {
                    lines: 74573,
                    key: "human"
                }
            ],
            extension: [
                {
                    lines: 13,
                    key: "without_extension"
                },
                {
                    lines: 4,
                    key: "py"
                },
                {
                    lines: 74556,
                    key: "sql"
                }
            ],
            language: [
                {
                    lines: 4,
                    key: "Python"
                },
                {
                    lines: 13,
                    key: "Undefined"
                },
                {
                    lines: 74556,
                    key: "SQL"
                }
            ],
            module: [

            ]
        }
    }
```

Thats for 1 revision. Now, I use query to group by days, so I expect proper sum of revisions by day. But strange thing: total is added properly, but by languages or extensions the sum is really bad.

```
{
    took: 4,
    timed_out: false,
    _shards: {
        total: 5,
        successful: 5,
        failed: 0
    },
    hits: {
        total: 21,
        max_score: 0,
        hits: [

        ]
    },
    aggregations: {
        articles_over_time: {
            buckets: [
                {
                    key_as_string: "2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                    key: 1421020800000,
                    doc_count: 2,
                    add_total: {
                        value: 1676461
                    },
                    add_language: {
                        buckets: [
                            {
                                key: "python",
                                doc_count: 2,
                                lines: {
                                    value: 1676461
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                key: "sql",
                                doc_count: 2,
                                lines: {
                                    value: 1676461
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                key: "undefined",
                                doc_count: 1,
                                lines: {
                                    value: 76124
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

As you can see, the sum of Python lines is equal to SQL lines, but this is actually a total sum of all lines.
Here is the query I use:

```
    http://localhost:9200/test5/svn/_search?pretty&source={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "project_id": "2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "articles_over_time": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "date",
                "interval": "day"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "add_language": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "revision_change.add.detail.language.key"
                    },
                    "aggs":{
                        "lines": {
                            "sum":{
                                "field": "revision_change.add.detail.language.lines"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "add_total":{
                    "sum":{
                        "field": "revision_change.add.detail.total"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Did somebody face this problem? Thanks for help.